# Converting Oracle Date and Time

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

How do I convert the following timestamp in Oracle :

```
12-MAY-2013 12:00:00 AM
```

to this

```
11-MAY-2013 24:00:00
```

Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suspect anyone trying to answer will need more context. For a start, you've given *textual* representations, whereas I'd expect the actual storage to be somewhat different. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to convert Oracle Date and Time format. If the initial storage in the database uses the following format '12-MAY-2013 12:00 AM', how do I convert the output of my SQL statement so that the format becomes '11-MAY-2013 24:00'? Can I use the TO_DATE function to achieve this? if so, what is the masking format I can use?

Comment: That really doesn't give much more context...

Comment: You ask for `11-MAY-2013 24:00:00`. Do you really need to output it this way, or standard Oracle (0-23) `12-MAY-2013 00:00:00` is OK with you?

Comment: Yes, I need the date output to be 'previous date' combined with '24:00:00'

Comment: 24:00:00 is nonsense. 12:00:00 a.m. is 00:00:00 in 24-hour format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** A possible solution

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dt - TRUNC(dt) = 0  
            THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(dt) - 1, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') || ' 24:00:00'
            ELSE TO_CHAR(dt, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       END dt
  FROM
(
  SELECT TO_DATE('12-MAY-2013 12:00:00 AM', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') dt
    FROM dual
)
```

Output:

```
|                   DT |
------------------------
| 11-May-2013 24:00:00 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12697)** demo

**Original answer** Try

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('12-MAY-2013 12:00:00 AM', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') dt
FROM dual
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12692)** demo

Comment: That doesn't give the output the OP specified. The OP wants "midnight at the start of May 12th" to be shown as "24:00 at the end of May 11th"

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough. Thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot achieve this using standard Oracle functions. Oracle uses values 0 - 23, if you need to display midnight like 24:00, you have to write your own function.